# WCF Web services and constructors

Tags: wcf, web-services, webservice-client, service-reference

I wrote a couple of simple web methods (as a part of WCF service) that use a couple of (more complex) classes as input/returned parameters. Each web method attributed by [OperationContract], each data class attributed by [DataContract], each data field in the classes attributed by [DataMethod].
On the client side I can call these web methods by adding Service Reference.
All things are fine, but when I create an instance of some of the data classes above on client side, their constructors don't run.
Because it's a little complicate to initialize each instance, every time, I thought there is some way to initialize instances on client side by their own constructors.
Thanks in advance!
Ilan.

Comment: Clarify your question. It is not clear what you mean by *their constructors don't run*?

Comment: The data classes (with their constructors) defined on server side (WCF web services VS2010 solution). But consuming of the web methods and creating instances of the classes above are in client application (via adding "Sevice Reference" in VS). So freshly created instances (in client side) don't call any constructor ;-(

Answer (score 1):

Methods exposed on data contracts (including constructors) in your service are only for service applications. Adding service reference will recreated only data structure of your data contract classes because service description is not able to describe logic and logic cannot be serialized.

All classes created with service reference are partial. You can create your own partial class and add your own custom constructors or you can [share the assembly](http://thejoyofcode.com/Sharing_types_between_the_client_and_the_server_in_WCF.aspx) with data contracts between your service and client (but it will share all logic added to your data contract classes which is most often what you don't want). Sharing assembly will tightly couple your client and service.